# Unable to activate constraint with anchors <NSLayoutXAxisAnchor:0x600000edbcc0 \" UIView:0x7ffb0848ee60.leading\">

Tags: ios, swift

I get the following error

```
"Unable to activate constraint with anchors <NSLayoutXAxisAnchor:0x600000edbcc0 \" UIView:0x7ffb0848ee60.leading\"> and <NSLayoutXAxisAnchor:0x600000e21f40 \" UIImageView:0x7ffb0848e140.leading\"> because they have no common ancestor.  Does the constraint or its anchors reference items in different view hierarchies?  That's illegal."
```

Here's my code

```
  class LearningItemDetailTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    
    let itemImage: UIImageView = {
        let imageView = UIImageView(frame: .zero)
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        imageView.clipsToBounds = true
        imageView.layer.masksToBounds = true
        imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return imageView
    }()
    
    
    let itemCompletedView : UIView = {
        let completedView = UIView(frame: .zero)
        completedView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.01, green: 0.07, blue: 0.13, alpha: 0.70)
        completedView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return completedView
    }()
    
    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        
        
        contentView.addSubview(itemImage)
        contentView.addSubview(itemCompletedView)
   
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            itemImage.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 20),
            itemImage.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.centerYAnchor),
            itemImage.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 110),
            itemImage.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 165)
        ])
        
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            itemCompletedView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: itemImage.leadingAnchor, constant: 0),
            itemCompletedView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: itemImage.trailingAnchor, constant: 0),
            itemCompletedView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: itemImage.topAnchor, constant: 0),
            itemCompletedView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 110),
            itemCompletedView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 165)
        ])
 }


required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: There are many possible errors here, but let's just focus on the biggest one: `layoutSubviews` is _not_ the place to add constraints! One reason is that it is called many times, so you're going to be adding those same constraints over and over.

Comment: Another possible issue is: what if this cell comes into existence by a call to `init(coder:)`? The subviews never get added as subviews.

Comment: I don't even know under what class you are writing code.

Comment: Where do you add constraints then?

Comment: updated with the class name

Comment: thanks for the help! Where do we put the constraints?

Comment: @ElTomato Can you please help? Please @matt?

Comment: I can't help you since you have lots of problems.  Why do you need init and required init?  Unless you are making an instance of the class, you don't need them.

Comment: I'm trying to create a custom table view cell. Where do I place the imageView and itemCompletedView as subView of the contentView? @ElTomato

Comment: @ElTomato I updated the code. Can you help now?

Comment: Try removing `itemImage.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 20),` since you have a center anchor. Might tackle one of the  issues.